# Set shortcut targetpath Wix

Tags: wix, shortcut-file

I want to set the shortcut target path in wix for an advertised shortcut
This is the code that creates the shorcut now:

```
<Component Id="APP_EXE" Directory="INSTALLDIR" DiskId="1" Guid="XXXX-XXXX">
<File Id="AppExe" Name="app.exe" Source="$(var.ComponentSourceDir)\$(var.ExeName)" KeyPath="yes">
    <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Advertise="yes" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="$(var.VersionedName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="MainIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" />
  </File>
</Component>
```

The target in shortcut properties window is readonly now and it displayes the application name. I cannot change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new component where I create the shortcut. I removed the previous one.

```
<Component Id="APP_EXE" Directory="INSTALLDIR" DiskId="1" Guid="XXXX-XXXX">
<File Id="AppExe" Name="app.exe" Source="$(var.ComponentSourceDir)\$(var.ExeName)" KeyPath="yes">
  </File>
</Component>
<Component Id="APP_SHORTCUT" Directory="INSTALLDIR" DiskId="1" Guid="XXXX_XXXXX">
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\APP\Installer" Name="desktopShortcut" Value="KeyPath" KeyPath="yes" Type="string" />
  <Shortcut Id="desktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="$(var.VersionedName)" WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Icon="MainIcon.exe" IconIndex="0" Target="[INSTALLDIR]app.exe"/>
</Component>
```